# joint density function of two independent random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that $_1$ and $_2$ are independent and follow a uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$. Let $_1 = _1 + _2$, and $_2 = _2 − _1$.

a) Find the joint pdf $_{_1,_2}
(_1, _2)$ of $_1$ and $_2$.

b) Sketch the region  = {(1, 2)} for $_{_1,_2}(_1, _2) > 0$.

I just find that $$f(Y_1) = \begin{cases}
y_1 & \text{for $0 < y_1 < 1$} \\
2-y_1 & \text{for $1 \le y_1 < 2$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

$$f(Y_2) = \begin{cases}
y_2+1 & \text{for $-1 < y_2 < 0$} \\
1-y_2 & \text{for $0 \le y_2 < 1$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

how about the next steps?

Comment: @KennyLau No they are not.  Fable has it correct. They have Triangle Distributions.

Answer (score 2):

$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{D}(y_1,y_2)$$
where $D$ is the square delimited by the points $(0,0),(1,1),(0,2),(-1,-1)$, which is the image of the unit square by the linear transformation
$\phi(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+x_2\\ x_2-x1\end{pmatrix}$.

To see this, let $h$ a non-negative measurable function. Then you can compute $E(h(Y_1,Y_2))$ using the substitution $\phi$. You'll see that the $\frac{1}{2}$ is the absolute value of the jacobian determinant of $\phi^{-1}$.
You should obtain $$E[h(Y_1,Y_2)]=\frac{1}{2}\int\int h(y_1,y_2)\mathbf{1}_D(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2$$
which proves the result.

Answer (score 1):

Because $~Y_1=X_1+X_2~,~ Y_2=X_2-X_1$

Then $~~~~~X_1=\dfrac{Y_1-Y_2}2~,~ X_2=\dfrac{Y_2+Y_1}2$

Therefore the Jacobian change of variable transformation is: $$\begin{align}f_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1, y_2) ~=~& f_{X_1}\Big(\frac{y_1-y_2}2\Big)~f_{X_2}\Big(\frac{y_1+y_2}2\Big)\left\lVert\dfrac{\partial (\frac{y_1-y_2}2,\frac{y_1+y_2}2)}{\partial (y_1,y_2)}\right\rVert\\ ~=~& \boxed? \cdot\mathbf 1_{(y_1,y_2)\in\mathcal D}\end{align}$$

The support domain $\mathcal D$ is the transformation of the support of $X_1,X_2$, which is the square $\Box(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,0)$.

$$\begin{align}\mathcal D~=~&\Diamond(0+0,0-0)(0+1,1-0)(1+1,1-1)(1+0,0-1)\\~=~&\Diamond(0,0)(1,1)(2,0)(1,{-1})\\~=~&\{(y_1,y_2)\in \boxed{?}\}\end{align}$$

Can you complete?

Comment: the absolute value of the jacobian determinant is 1/2

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The joint density of $(X_1, X_2)$ is easy to compute (product of marginal densities). Write the random vector $(Y_1,Y_2) = A (X_1,X_2)$ where $A$ is the matrix

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Do you know how to compute the "transformed" joint density?

Comment: The main trouble the OP is facing is how to deal with *the domain* of the PDF, not the value of the PDF on its domain, it seems, but your answer does not even mention this aspect.

Comment: I disagree on this point. The question asks point a) and b). The only step in the question regards solving a) and my hint was about solving a). Once done this, solving b) should be pretty straightforward. Besides "The main trouble the OP is facing is how to deal with the domain of the PDF" is not a fact (did he ask about only the domain?). I assumed he was facing the entire problem.

Comment: Not stated by the OP, easily deducted from the context. Nota: my first comment is a suggestion to reach a better answer (a *complete* one, to begin with). If you read it as an attack, I am not interested.

Comment: Nope I was just explaining why I answered in that way. We're not fighting here, just adding knowledge. Now, being a pretty basic question, my intent was to give an hint, not a complete answer.

Comment: This answer is okay in my view. I like hints, especially if they go along with an inviting question to the OP: "do you know how to...". Elaboration can follow later, if necessary.

Comment: It is good news that "we're not fighting here", the tone of your first comment sounded otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is what has emerged from my reply that was, again, only an explanation of why I disagreed.