# Distribution of a process dependent on a Markov chain's states

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain $X_t$ with state space $\{0,1\}$, initial distribution 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{P}(X_0=1)=\lambda \\
\mathbf{P}(X_0=0)=1-\lambda
\end{array}
$$

and transition probabilities

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{P}(X_t=1|X_{t-1}=1)=p_a \\
\mathbf{P}(X_t=0|X_{t-1}=1)=1-p_a \\
\mathbf{P}(X_t=0|X_{t-1}=0)=p_b  \\
\mathbf{P}(X_t=1|X_{t-1}=0)=1-p_b 
\end{array}
$$

Now consider the process 
$$
Y_n = \sum_{t=0}^n X_t 
$$

I'm interested in computing the distribution of $Y_n$ and $\max_{0\leq t \leq n} Y_t$.

Of course I could simulate the chain, but are there closed form expressions for those distributions?

Comment: The chain $Y$ is nondecreasing hence the "max" part is bizarre. To compute recursively the distribution of every $Y_n$, consider the pairs of functions $$a_n(s)=E(s^{Y_n};X_n=1)\qquad b_n(s)=E(s^{Y_n};X_n=0)$$ and note that simple formulas link $(a_{n+1}(s),b_{n+1}(s))$ to $(a_{n}(s),b_{n}(s))$ and that the distribution of $Y_n$ is fully characterized by $$E(s^{Y_n})=a_n(s)+b_n(s).$$

Comment: Got to an answer after the comment, thanks. Anyway can you explicit your suggestion (which seems far more elegant than mine)?

Comment: @Did Since $Y_0=X_0$ wouldn't we have $$\mathbb E[s^{Y_0}\mid X_0=i]  = \mathbb E[s^{Y_0}\mid Y_0=i] = s^i$$ while $$\mathbb E[s^{Y_0}] =  1-\lambda + \lambda(s),$$ meaning we should define $a_0(s) = 1-\lambda$ and $b_0(s) = \lambda s$?

Comment: @Did why does the distribution of $Y_n$ is fully characterized by $\mathbb{E}(s^Y_n)$?

Comment: @GabrieleCacchioni $Y_n$ is a nonnegative integer-valued random variable, and hence corresponds uniquely to the generating function $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb P(Y_n=j)s^j.$$

Comment: @Math1000 Got it (now). But is there a method to get the density from the pgf? Or to approximate it in some way (I would need $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=k)$ with a good approximation)? I'm reading that this should be like the k-th derivative of the pgf evaluated in 0...

Comment: @Did even I write down the recursion, then to get $P(Y_n=j)$ I should compute the j-th derivative of $E(s^{Y_n})$ evaluated in 0. What if this isn't possible in practice?

Comment: @GabrieleCacchioni Yes there are cases when extracting the coefficients of the series is difficult, of course. To decide whether the present one is one of them, we ought to see your tries to solve it (which, rather amazingly, we still have no idea about, 10+ days after you asked the question).

Comment: Yes, more or less. The question was: assume extracting the coefficients is difficult, the only other way is the simulation? (

Comment: It's that I actually don't have tries because I'm stuck in the recursion. If $a_0(s) = E(s^{Y_0};X_0=1)=\lambda s$ and $b_0(s) = E(s^{Y_0};X_0=0)=1-\lambda$, I can't find how to write $a_1(s)$ and $b_1(s)$ as a function of $a_0(s)$ and $b_0(s)$, imagine to write down the general term :(

Comment: And we have to wait 11 days to learn that you are unable to exploit the indications in my first comment? Why is that? A conjecture is that you did not bother before because you waited for a complete solution to pop up on the page but that, now that it is more or less clear it will not, you come back to ask once again for the final formula. True? Anyway, please explain in detail why you are stuck. Which recursion did you try to get $a$ and $b$ at times $n+1$ from $a$ and $b$ at time $n$?

Comment: Actually, the only reason I didn't work on this is that this is not a life-or-death question, is just curiosity. So I simply didn't have the time, that's it. To be honest I think your "style" of comments is against me because of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772442/joint-density-function-of-two-independent-random-variables/1772456#1772456 in which we had a misunderstanding (I was new, I didn't know that comments are for hints, and answers are for complete answers). I'm sorry if you still think that my comment was an attack: again it wasn't.

Comment: Anyway: $E(s^{Y_n};X_n=1) = E(s^{Y_{n-1}+X_n};X_n=1)$. Now, is it possible to write $ E(s^{Y_{n-1}+1};X_n=1)P(X_n=1)$? If this is true (and I don't know), how can we relate it with $b_n$ and $a_n$?

Comment: Sorry to infirm your fantasies but, eventhough your behaviour on the other page (which frankly I had forgotten) was definitely substandard for the reasons explained there, this is no motivation for my remarks here. Please stick to the maths. Reminder: $E(Z;A)$ is the expectation of $Z$ on the event $A$, not conditionally on $A$, that is, $$E(X;A)=E(X\mathbf 1_A)=\int_AXdP,$$ while, if $P(A)\ne0$, $$E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(X;A)}{P(A)}.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for clarifying the notation; I interpreted $\mathbb E[X;A]$ as $\mathbb E[X\mid A]$ since I would write $\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_A]$ to denote $\int_A X\ \mathsf d \mathbb P$ and haven't seen $\mathbb E[\cdot ;\cdot]$ used for that before..

Comment: $$
\mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}] = \mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n}+X_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}]=  \mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n}+X_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n}=1}]+ \mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n}+X_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n}=0}]=\mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n}+X_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}|{X_{n}=1}]\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=1)+ \mathbb{E}[s^{Y_{n}+X_{n+1}}\mathbf{1}_{X_{n+1}=1}|{X_{n}=0}]\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0)
$$
Now (if the above is correct), the conditioning on $X_n$ should be useful. Am I on the good way?

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on @Did's comment (letting $a_0(s)=\lambda s$ and $b_0(s)=1-\lambda$ as according to the initial distribution), we have the recurrences
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}(s) &= p_asa_n(s) + (1-p_b)sb_n(s),\\
b_{n+1}(s) &= (1-p_a)a_n(s) + p_b b_n(s).
\end{align}
Adding these yields
$$a_{n+1}(s) + b_{n+1}(s) = (1-p_a+p_as)a_n(s) + (1-p_b+p_bs)b_n(s),  $$
so
$$a_{n+1}(s) + b_{n+1}(s) = (1-p_a+p_as)^n\lambda s + (1-p_b+p_bs)^n(1-\lambda).$$
It follows that $$Y_n\stackrel d= \lambda(B_{n,a}+1) + (1-\lambda)B_{n,b} $$
where $B_{n,a}\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p_a)$ and $B_{n,b}\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p_b)$.

Comment: The recursion is wrong.

Comment: @Did I can't get why this one is wrong, also. Maybe $a_0(s)=\lambda s$ and $b_0(s)=1-\lambda$? Or the actual recursion?

Comment: @GabrieleCacchioni Indeed I had $a_0$ and $b_0$ mixed up - I think it is correct now.